# MS SQL connection fails over local network

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, webforms

I am developing some .net c# webforms, relying on a connection to a MS SQL db. Development configuration has a localhost\SQLEXPRESS db server, production is deployed on web; in my web.config I have set the two connection strings, choosing one of them at a time, as needed; everything seemed to work fine when an issue arose; if I call my webforms directly from VS express for web in debug, or from the web broswer in the same pc, connections work fine both with local db and web db; if I call my webforms from a web browser in the lan, they work fine only if I choose the web db, but if I choose the local db, no data is retrieved, so I guess the connection to local db fails (c# code gets executed, though); it used to work fine before, and, still, the same webforms activated from VS do work fine, so connection strings should be ok... what now?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it?  If not, what do you mean by "no data is retrieved"?

Comment: @user236739, what now..!!! is the same question I have for your Question

Comment: no, I don't get any error message, at least from the browser; with 'no data is retrieved' I mean that I am sure that the c# code gets executed, but the json string built on the select statements contains empty fields; the part of the json string built directly in the aspx is returned correctly; that's way I suppose that connection to db fails

Comment: "contains empty fields" = "gives no records"

Answer (score 0):

Solved. By moving site deployment (publish...) from c:inetpub/wwwroot/ to a virtual directory (in the machine where both VS e MS SQL are installed);